# How to obtain the longpoll url using jsonRPCClient

Tags: bitcoind

I'm trying to find the longpoll url for my pool. I've found documentation saying that it is within the headers but I'm unable to see anything. Is there any way to retreave the url via an RPC request? or is the url something that can be easily worked out? I'm using bitcoind and eliopool.
Thanks, James.